# Should a BoxCox transformation to normalize the skewness of data be applied to all the predictors?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, descriptive-statistics, skewness

If there are few predictors that are highly skewed among a larger set of predictors in case of a linear regression problem, should a BoxCox transformation be applied to only these few predictors or should it be applied to all the predictors present in the set - I know that the remaining of the predictors are actually not skewed, it is just a few of them.

Comment: Why would you do this\* to any of the predictors?  $\quad$\*(remove the skewness, I mean; one might consider transformation of predictors for other reasons)

Comment: The key point with linear regression is linearity. Skewness of any marginal distribution is secondary or irrelevant as such unless it is so extreme that the story is dominated by outliers.